# Find the mean value of two values in different files with numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the average value of values that are in different json files with numpy.
This value will have a `"avg_total"`

An example of the json structure:

```
[{
  "objectID": 1,
  "avg_annnonces": 10000},
 {
  "objectID": 2,
  "avg_annnonces": 20000}]
```

The same structure applies to the second json file, with a `"avg_actual"` key.

The python code:

```
import json
import numpy as np

with open('rzc/output/demo/rzc_demo-2019-09-09.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

with open('output/output_format/demo2019-07-29_demo_format.json', encoding='utf-8') as datademo_file:
    dataAuctions = json.loads(datademo_file.read())

for rzc in data:
    avgAnnonces = rzc["avg_annonces"]

    for gm in dataAuctions:
        objectIdRzc = rzc["objectID"]
        objectIdGm = gm["objectID"]

        avgGm = gm["avg_actual"]

        if objectIdRzc == objectIdGm:
            gm["avg_total"] = []
            avgTotal = gm["avgTotal"]
            if avgAnnonces and avgGm is not None:
                    gm["avg_total"] = np.mean(?)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
import numpy as np
np.mean([d['avg_annnonces'] for d in data])
```

where `data` is something like your JSON:

```
[{"objectID": 1, "avg_annnonces": 10000},
 {"objectID": 2, "avg_annnonces": 20000}]
```